# how to set values in cookie and send that cookie in url in android

Tags: java, android

## Cookie

am new to android and cookie concept, plz guys help me how insert a some value device number,device version and phone model name in cookies and tat cookie send into an url.i saw lot of examples but i dont know exact part.. am in still in confusion.plz guys solve my problem.phone model,device name,os version into cookie,send cookie into an url.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are not send in the url, they are sent in the HTTP header.

What library are you using ? It should have a method for sending cookies in the request.

Comment: am using httpget method.  want a string value put in cookie tat cookie  insert into http header?

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you really need is to make cookie visible to server so it will look like normal HTTP request from browser. Is that right? 
Then you don't need to insert cookie in URL.

Cookie is a special content that is sent with request headers. It is normally not exposed to user.

So what you probably need is some Java library that will handle the HTTP protocol for you. Just google some, there are plenty of them for both Java EE and for Android. They will much simplify how you can deal with HTTP requests.

Also I am not really familiar with Android development but I reckon that framework itself should have ability to manage HTTP requests with no problem. Maybe some documentation lookup will help?